# How can I get python to understand my commands such as python manage.py shell. Error code: python bash: command not found

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

What are the details of your problem?

I am trying to run the command python manage.py shell. I am in the directory that has manage.py but python is acting like I don't have the file or the command ability for shell.

I am using visual studio code and I ran the echo$PATH command and got this output:

> /Users/andrewstribling/Desktop/mike_mysite/project_env/bin:/Users/andrewstribling/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/andrewstribling/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin

i had installed anaconda but went back to visual studio code. is this tied to it?

Also, my director has my project env folder inside of my project folder.

What did you try and what were you expecting?

I have tried deleting the project_env folder for my enviornment and creating another one.

I have reached out to the discord community for django and have not gotten a response.

I looked up venv errors on stack overflow and I am not understanding the Path Variable really is or how to change it.

I have read stack over flow articles but I do not believe their situation applies to me.

https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv#How_a_Python_venv_works

I expect that there is a way to change how my project is seeing this.

clarification:
bash is the terminal type that I am using in visual studio code.
when I type in: python manage.py shell

the command has some stuff come before it.

(project_env) Andrews-MBP:mysite andrewstribling$ python manage.py shell

project_env is my virtual environment.

my name is Andrew and I percieve that visual studio code is using my user folder

mysite is the name of my project.

bash: python: command not found is what I am getting in the output after running the command.

I apologize, I am new to programming. I do not see any other errors. is there a place I can look?

Comment: Please put the EXACT error message in your question.  What you said in your title makes no sense.  Why would bash be involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

attempting python3 instead of python is a workaround as well!

it seems that if I create a new bash terminal and close everything out that might work.

re opening folders is not a bad idea.

attempting python3 instead of python is a workaround as well!
It seems every time I leave my project the environment stops working. I will need to use the deactivate command when I leave my project.